# Changing a call on a pocket for an 8 ball

Tags: rules, pool

When you call a pocket and miss the shot for the 8 ball, on your next turn can you call a different pocket or do you still have to try to shoot the 8 ball in the original pocket?

Answer (score 3):

In BCA eight ball each players calls ball on pocket on each shot and each shot is considered different. The choice of pocket from the player's previous shot has no effect on the choice of pocket for the current shot for any of the balls, including the eight ball.